# Translating Kohana-modules in a convenient way?

Tags: php, localization, kohana, gettext

I have been looking for a convenient way of making and maintaining translations of my Kohana-modules. I have played around with POEdit and have extracted all __()'s from my modules. Really like the way POedit works, and it's just to run a quick update to gather all new strings and save a new catalog later on. I could afterwards [convert the po-files to PHP-arrays](http://www.rogerdudler.com/?p=342) sort of...it seems a bit complicated with all steps.

I have seen [this approach](http://blog.mixu.net/2010/12/09/kohana-translate-an-i18n-module-for-collecting-translations/) but I would rather not install tables and new modules for translations, I think this gets to complicated and "drupalish" ;-).

How do you managing localizations and translations on different languages in your Kohana-projects? Any hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it. First of all POEdit for Mac is very buggy and strange, unfortunately.

In POEdit, created a new catalog with correct path and __ as a keyword.

Run POEdit to extract all the strings.

After this I ran this simple PHP-script over the generated PO-file. The output from the script I pasted into the files in i18n-folder of the project.

```
$file = 'sv_SE.po';
$translations = array();
$po = file($file);
$current = null;
foreach ($po as $line) {
    if (substr($line,0,5) == 'msgid') {
        $current = trim(substr(trim(substr($line,5)),1,-1));
    }
    if (substr($line,0,6) == 'msgstr') {
        $translations[$current] = trim(substr(trim(substr($line,6)),1,-1));
    }
}

echo "<?php\n\n";
foreach ($translations as $msgid => $msgstr) {
    echo '\'' . $msgid . '\' => \'' . $msgstr . "',\n";
}
echo "\n?>";
```

By using POEdit it's easy to maintain the project-localizations since it's syncing all the strings but just clicking "Update". I'll get a report of new and obsolete strings and can update the localizations in a few moments. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [I18n_Plural module](https://github.com/czukowski/I18n_Plural). I like how it handles plural forms, very simple and easy. There is a lot of examples in readme file (showing on a main module page).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Seems quite impressive but maybe too advanced for my needs. Will look into it later.